# Associate 2 pages' analytics datas

Tags: .htaccess, google-analytics, analytics

I have a page with this url : `example.com/someurl`.

For some reason, I made a 301 redirection on it to `example.com/some-url`
But I would like to make sure that ancient datas for the first url will be associated with my new url.

Because if I export my datas, I'll have two entries which means two different pages, but actually this is only one page.

Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

Alas this doesn't work to well. Your best chance would be to use virtual pageview and pass in the old url to the pageview tracking on the new page:

```
ga("send","pageview","/some-url");
```

Alternatively you can create a filter in your GA view settings that rewrites the new url to the old url.

This will work for newly incoming hits. Data that's already connected will not change, and you cannot really consolidate after the fact.

Answer (score 0):

You can use filter in settings
Filter Type: Search and Replace
field request URI

```
Search String: /some-url
Replace String: /someurl
```

And its merge wtih historical data